# I'm having trouble migrating from Universal Analytics (v3) to Google Analytics v4

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have a PHP application that collects data from Universal Analytics, but now there's no more data, and I need to retrieve data from GA4. I've tried to update the functions according to the documentation, but I'm having trouble. Below, I'll show how it's done with Universal Analytics, and I'm looking for assistance in connecting to GA4.

```
parent::__construct($client);
$this->rootUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/';
$this->servicePath = 'analytics/v3/';
$this->version = 'v3';
$this->serviceName = 'analytics';

$this->data_realtime = new Google_Service_Analytics_DataRealtime_Resource(
    $this,
    $this->serviceName,
    'realtime',
    array(
        'methods' => array(
            'get' => array(
                'path' => 'data/realtime',
                'httpMethod' => 'GET',
                'parameters' => array(
                    'ids' => array(
                        'location' => 'query',
                        'type' => 'string',
                        'required' => true,
                    ),
                    'metrics' => array(
                        'location' => 'query',
                        'type' => 'string',
                        'required' => true,
                    ),
                    'max-results' => array(
                        'location' => 'query',
                        'type' => 'integer',
                    ),
                    'sort' => array(
                        'location' => 'query',
                        'type' => 'string',
                    ),
                    'dimensions' => array(
                        'location' => 'query',
                        'type' => 'string',
                    ),
                    'filters' => array(
                        'location' => 'query',
                        'type' => 'string',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        )
    )
);
-----------------------------
$chave = json_decode(file_get_contents('linkxxxx8416.json'));
$credentials = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    'email.gserviceaccount.com',
    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly'),
    $chave->private_key
);

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAssertionCredentials($credentials);

if ($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion();
}

$ga = new Google_Service_Analytics($client);

$results = $ga->data_realtime->get('ga:xxxxxxxxxxx', 'rt:activeUsers', array('dimensions' => 'rt:pagePath, rt:pageTitle', 'sort' => '-rt:activeUsers', 'max-results' => 10, 'filters' => 'rt:pagePath=~/\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}.+'));
```